# Problem with asmx webmethod that uses Mysql Load Data local infile

Tags: asp.net, mysql, web-services

When I use the following in a webmethod:

```
string mysqlsPath = Server.MapPath("applog.txt");
            command.CommandText = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + mysqlsPath + "' INTO TABLE numbers FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
```

I get Error **LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ---> Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\inetpubwwwrootwebservicesapplog.txt'**

When looking at this error i noticed that after "inet"  its dropping the "\" between the rest of the directories, what could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to escape the mysqlsPath variale first.

Something like this would do the trick

```
 mysqlsPath = mysqlsPath.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```

This will convert the \ to \ so the c# won't remove it.

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly, didn't know C# would remove stuff like that